# Don't notify site inside webview when its visibility has changed

Tags: java, android, webview

When i switch the screen of the phone off webview inside my app fires 'visibilitychange' event to website, but I need to block that behavior, because that site stops working when visibility is 'hidden'. How to prevent that?

Comment: is your activity calling onPause? or onResume?

Comment: @Dylan I only have bare activity that loads url with website.


```public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    WebView myWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myWebView = findViewById(R.id.webview);

        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.loadUrl("https://example.com");
    }
}```